# Removing indentation from the 1st chapter line

Tags: chapters, indentation, book-design

On my pdf document, the first line appears indented. However, I'd like to remove this indentation. Of course, adding '\noindent` will solve the problem, but doing that will force the users to typewrite this command wherever there is a chapter. And more, they need to be careful to check if the same matter is not happening in the sections and subsections.

In general, only the first line of each chapter is indented. How can I force latex to remove this indentation from the first line? Because, from what I read, it should have no indentation for book-based templates, as the `.cls` I am working with.

Comment: by default in most classes the first line after a heading is not indented so to tell you what to change we probably need more information to know why you are not getting that.

Comment: That's the problem the '.cls' has been modified by several people. And I am not one of them.

Comment: perhaps so but if you want help you need to give at least _some_ clues to the people trying to help you

Comment: as always it is much easier for you to make a test example than for others to guess what might be wrong. make a file `\documentclass{myclass}\begin{document}\chapter{abc}xyz\\123\end{document}` that shows xyz indented, then delete everything from `myclass.cls` not related to chapters, check the problem still occurs and edit your question to show the document and remaoning class file, then someone will debug it.